# find if the value present in text file values using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a list of Contract numbers in a text file.

```
185
166
504
506
507
510
509
```

I have servername like **SERVER999AUTO1**. I need to check if the number **999** present in the file. if present then, no operation else we have to perform certain operation.

I tried below, but for each contract it is printing the else value

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\list.txt"
$containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match "SERVER999AUTO1"}
if ($containsWord -contains $true) {
    Write-Host "There is!"
} else {
    Write-Host "There ins't!"
}
```

Please let me know on this.

Comment: Your file is a List of numbers  however your trying to match the word SERVER999AUTO1, where does that come from?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: If you see the number in the string **999**, I have to match that if that is part of the file or not.

Comment: Besides the value actually not being in your .txt file, you're attempting to match the current number to `"SERVER999AUTO1"`, which it won't match it. In other words, your precedence is wrong when it's supposed to be: `"SERVER999AUTO1" -match $_`. Change it to that and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although a bit unclear, you can parse the value from the servername and look for it in the text file like so:

```
$serverName = 'SERVER999AUTO1'
$valueISeek = ([regex]'(?i)server(\d+).*').Match($serverName).Groups[1].Value

if ((Get-Content "C:\list.txt") -contains $valueISeek) {
    Write-Host "Value '$valueISeek' found!" -ForegroundColor Green
} else {
    Write-Host "Value '$valueISeek' could not be found!" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Regex details:

```
(?i)         Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i)
server       Match the characters “server” literally
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d        Match a single digit 0..9
      +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)           
.            Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. what changes I have to have if the starting the name doesn't have **SERVER**. e.g. **A92SW999AUTO1AP/B97SW999AUTO1AP**

Comment: @EmptyCoder, if the number of interest is always a _3-digit sequence_, you can use the following: `$valueISeek = $serverName -replace '.+(\d{3}).+', '$1'`

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment...

The reason why your `else` block is activated is because, your current iteration of the number you're on itself does not match *"SERVER999AUTO1"*. You need to switch the order as *"SERVER999AUTO1"* matches *"999"*, not the other way around:

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\list.txt"
$containsWord = $file | %{"SERVER999AUTO1" -match $_}
if ($containsWord -contains $true) {
    Write-Host "There is!"
} else {
    Write-Host "There ins't!"
}
```

Reversing the order to the correct order will work. In this case, I personally would use a `switch` statement as it can perform multiple conditions with a "cleaner" look:

```
$toMatch = "SERVER999AUTO1"
switch -File ("C:\list.txt")
{
    {$toMatch -match $_} { "There is!"; Break }
    default {"There isn't" }
}
```

... then again, it's all just preference.

Comment: it is fine but I want the result to be printed once. not multiple time

Comment: @EmptyCoder, good thing it only does it once:) hence the `Break`.